# MediaElement Source throws Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I have a Silverlight application hosted on a website. I want to use the MediaElement control in Silverlight to display a video. If I set the Source property of the MediaElement to a URI on the web ( such as http://www.jhepple.com/SampleMovies/niceday.wmv) it works and the video is played. However, if I download the video to my application and try to reference it like

```
video.Source = new Uri("niceday.wmv");
```

the MediaElement throws the error

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

How can I get the MediaElement control to play a file that is local to the Silverlight app? Also, what should be the location of the video file .wmv?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use MediaStreamSource. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/CustomMediaStreamSource.aspx) on CodeProject provides a good tutorial and sample code .
Add the media file to your Assets in Blend or Visual Studio